# How to write a file in a path defined as a variable?

Tags: python

I am trying to save a file in a path defined with a variable:

```
from pathlib import Path

home = os.getcwd()
path = home + "\\template"
some_file = path + "\\some_file.html"

with open(some_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write("some text")
```

I get an error

```
with open(some_file, 'w') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\...
```

The some_file.html file exists in template folder.

Comment: What do you get when you do `print(some_file)`? Is it what you expected?

Comment: It would be much better to use `pathlib.Path` or at the very least use `os.path.join()`... Anyway as the `'w'` flag will actually create the file if it is not found, this means that the path to the folder itself is wrong

Comment: yea, I get a file path C:\Users\... where .html file is located

Comment: I can see you already imported `Path`, why not use it? Try `some_file = Path("template", "some_file.html")`

Comment: i get same error, i think it's something to do with "\\" and "\" in the file path, but dont know how to fix it

Comment: If you don’t show the actual path you get in the exception or in the print without omitting the interesting parts with ... it is not possible to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.path.join` function,
e.g. `some_file = os.path.join(home, "template", "some_file.html")`

Comment: I get the same error. Also in the error path is in "'C:\\Users\\..." format, if i do print(some_file), it has  "'C:\Users\..."  format

Comment: check that folder `template` exists, or create it with `os.makedirs`: `os.makedirs(path)`

Comment: it exists and some_file.html is inside, created manually, i just need to re write it without defining file path manually

Comment: @AndreyKhoronko you shoud edit your answer to be complete and elaborate enough explanation to the problem. Not just throw line of code and then posting more info as comments.